# Existance of regular semisimple elements in a torus

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I had asked a question about regular semisimple elements in finite simple group of Lie type in this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714029/existance-of-semisimple-elements-in-a-torus
Actually I wanted to know that is it true that every torus in finite simple group of lie type namely $G$ over finite field of order $q$ contains a regular semisimple element?
Jack Schmidt had led me to a MO discussion which I think it says the that statement is true for large enough $q$.

Recently I have read an article [The number of regular ...](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869383710550): which says :

"Suppose $\{\mathbb{C}\}$ is the set of regular conjugacy classes of $G$ whose centralizer is $G$-conjugate to a twisted maximal torus $T_{[w]}$ wher $[w]$ is .... .
Then $|\{\mathbb{C}\}|=|T(w,Q)|/|Z_W(w)|$."

Now I want to conclude from this statement that $|\{\mathbb{C}\}|\neq 0$ for every maximal torus of $G$. Is it true?

Comment: I would check GL(2,2): It has two conjugacy classes of maximal tori: one of order 1 and one of order 3. No element of a non-identity finite group has a centralizer of order 1, so one of those tori has an empty C. I use the definition of maximal tori as the F-fixed points of a F-stable maximal torus of the algebraic group G-bar (the infinite group). The maximal tori of order 1 is the maximally split maximal torus of diagonal matrices.

Comment: The statement in the article is mostly just orbit-stabilizer: it says "To count all regular conjugacy classes whose centralizer is G-conjugate to T, it suffices to count regular elements within T, and divide by the appropriate factor from the Weyl group to handle conjugacy." In other words, sometimes $|T(w,\varnothing)|=0$.

Comment: @ Jack Schmidt: $|T(w,\phi?)|$ doesn't mean the order of maximal torus related to $w$ and $\phi$?

Comment: You cut the quote off at the end of a sentence. The sentence you quote continues “where $T(w,\varnothing)$ denotes the set of regular elements in $T_{[w]}\ldots$” page 483.

Comment: Ok! you are right. Tanks a lot for your good point.